# Ubuntu 14.04 eclipse mars.2(4.5.2) I installed the latest version of google plugin for eclipse(4.3) and still its icon does not appear on the toolbar

Tags: linux, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

I followed all the steps correctly after seeing it`s not working I uninstalled and began all installation afresh and still the icon does not appear. Should I downgrade eclipse to luna4.4?Or how do I solve this problem?My java version is  1.7.0_80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I changed my eclipse version to luna 4.4 then followed this guideline https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4 and the icon appeared.

Comment: Plugin for eclipse mars 4.5 released on 31 March did you try it?